# String that contains line breaks

Tags: javascript, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/how-to-create-multiline-strings)

I have a lot of strings that I want to put in variables, but there is line breaks that aren't accepted.

Firefox says "Unterminated string literal" when I write :

```
var a="foo
bar";
```

Is there a way to write my strings without removing the line breaks manually?

Comment: Yes, use a search and replace and let a PROGRAM do it for you instead of doing it manually.

Comment: How can I write the `find & replace` to catch line breaks?

Comment: @user1365010: Enable regular expression/extended matching and type `\n`.

Comment: @user1365010 - If you're just trying to find & replace newlines in a text editor, most decent text editors allow you to search by an escape code (like `\n`) or a regular expression.  Notepad2 is my personal favorite.

Comment: I have `TextWrangler`, and it doesn't find any occurence with `\n`

Comment: Yea I have TextWranger on my Mac and it doesn't seem to have this feature, very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is not acceptable:

```
var a="foo" +
"bar";
```

Or as @minitech (the new mod) suggested:

```
var a="foo \
bar";
```

Then the answer is no.

Comment: Why not just use a backslash?

Comment: @minitech. What do you mean? you can edit if you wish, or answer yourself ofcourse.

Comment: I mean what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/805113/707111) says.

Comment: @minitech. Cool, didn't know it's possible, not that I'll ever user it... :) Good luck with the election!

Comment: @minitech. I saw in the comments that it's not a EMCA standard, anyway it shouldn't really be used... :)

Comment: Also, neither of these methods are actually preserving the new line; which I assume is important.

Answer (score 0):

Is this script generated dynamically by a web server?

If so, this web server will need to convert line breaks to the `\n` escape sequence instead.  You'll also have the same issue with other reserved characters, such as the backslash and double-quotes.

Some languages allow you to literally write a string constant (such as the `@` prefix in C#), however Javascript has no such feature standard, thus certain characters must be escaped.